# Check if first char position 1 is a letter position 2 and 3 a number in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im having some trouble combining two formulas in an if statement. I have a range of 6 columns which may contain a  string with a  length of 7, this string always starts with a letter followed by two random numbers (the rest of the string is random letter and numbers)

Im interested in finding every 7len string that starts with a letter followed by numbers in position 2 and 3. If the criteria are met the row is marked with a 1.

What I have counts every string with a lenght of 7

```
=IF(AND(LEN(J2)=7,(ISERR(LEFT(J2,1)*1))),1,0)
```

Comment: Lots of examples on here showing formulae or regex, check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```
=LET(
lengthOf7,LEN(A2)=7,
firstLetter,NOT(ISNUMBER(LEFT(A2,1)*1)),
secondThirdNumber,ISNUMBER(MID(A2,2,2)*1),
AND(lengthOf7,firstLetter,secondThirdNumber)
)
```

It checks all your conditions and "names" them to be more readable.

If you don't have Excel 365 then you can use it like this:

```
=AND((LEN(A2)=7), NOT(ISNUMBER(LEFT(A2,1)*1), ISNUMBER(MID(A2,2,2)*1))
```

Comment: Hi Ike, would this work if the first character was a special character (like @,*,&, etc.) ?

Comment: Yes it would. I am not checking for the CODE as you do - but only if it is not numeric.

Comment: @Ike That did the trick! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `FILTERXML()` to validate the string value:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&UPPER(A1)&"</s></t>","//s[translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')*0=0][substring(.,1,1)*0!=0][substring(.,2,2)*0=0][string-length()=7]")))
```

Where:

- `"<t><s>"&UPPER(A1)&"</s></t>"` - Creates a valid xml-string using the input from `A1` in uppercase;
- `[translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')*0=0]` - Checks if when all uppercase letters are removed, the remainder multiplied by zero equals zero. This validates only letters and numbers across the input;
- `[substring(.,1,1)*0!=0]` - Validates that the first character in the string is not equal to zero when multiplied by zero (thus being a letter);
- `[substring(.,2,2)*0=0]` - Validates that the substring from the 2nd character with a length of two equals zero when multiplied by zero (thus being numeric);
- `[string-length()=7]` - Validates that the total length of the node equals seven.

---

If you have ms365, you could actually also use `REDUCE()` to mimic the above and be less verbose:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(REDUCE(UPPER(A1),CHAR(SEQUENCE(24,,65)),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,"")))*1),ISERROR(LEFT(A1)*1),ISNUMBER(MID(A1,2,2)*1),LEN(A1)=7)
```

In this case the recursive `SUBSTITUTE()` will replace all uppercase letters with an empty string in order to make sure that the remainder is numeric. The other nested `AND()` parameters are rather self-explainatory.

---

**Note:** `WAAR` and `ONWAAR` are the Dutch equivalent to `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=IF(AND(LEN(A1)=7,OR(AND(CODE(MID(A1,1,1))>=65,CODE(MID(A1,1,1))<=90),AND(CODE(MID(A1,1,1))>=97,CODE(MID(A1,1,1))<=122)),CODE(MID(A1,2,1))>47,CODE(MID(A1,2,1))<58,CODE(MID(A1,3,1))>47,CODE(MID(A1,3,1))<58),1,0)
```